# PySpark - saving JSON column to Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to insert PySpark DataFrame with JSON / struct column to Postgres. My data:

```
+---------+------------+-------------+----------+
|  user_id|    group_id|point_balance|   details|
+---------+------------+-------------+----------+
|        1|           1|          777|      null|
|        2|           1|          888|      null|
|        3|           2|          168|      null|
|        4|           2|          425|{1, thing}|
+---------+------------+-------------+----------+
```

`details` is of type `struct<abc:bigint,some:string>` (this is test data, so those are example JSON keys and values).

I'm trying to save the data to local Postgres:

```
db_url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/test_db"
table = "user_points"

(
    user_points
    .write
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", db_url)
    .option("dbtable", table)
    .option("user", "postgres")
    .option("password", "postgres")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .save()
)
```

I get error `IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for struct<abc:bigint,some:string>`.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67601685/spark-write-dataframe-with-hashmap-to-postgres-as-json):

```
(
    user_points
    .select("user_id", "group_id", "point_balance", F.to_json(F.struct("details)).alias("details))
    .write
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", db_url)
    .option("dbtable", table)
    .option("user", "postgres")
    .option("password", "postgres")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .save()
)
```

This works, but it creates column of type `TEXT`, while I want proper `JSONB`.

Explicitly using `JSONB` does not work:

```
.option("createTableColumnTypes", "user_id INTEGER, group_id INTEGER, point_balance INTEGER, details JSONB")
```

```
ParseException: 
DataType jsonb is not supported.(line 1, pos 72)

== SQL ==
user_id INTEGER, group_id INTEGER, point_balance INTEGER, details JSONB
------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

How can I achieve that? I would prefer to do this in Spark, but casting in Postgres would also be ok.